# Javascript errors showing on site, assets folder not found

Tags: joomla-2.5, javascript

This page:

http://www.smithsdetection.com/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=19:prime-alert&Itemid=1417&lang=en#.V4YfGzVctmM

is showing the various javascript errors:

[image]

When you look at the location of these files, this location doesn't exist in the site structure - details.js is showing as http://www.smithsdetection.com/templates/blank/js/shims/details.js but the /shims/ folder doesn't exist.

Comment: Where are these files being loaded from and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must download and copy Webshim library files to your "blank" template, maybe you have misconfigured something in a extension.

The download link is at

http://afarkas.github.io/webshim/demos/index.html

Look for webshims.1.15.10/js-webshim/minified and copy shims folder to your templates/blank folder.

All "syntax error: expected expression, got '<'" are 404 pages being interpreted as javascript.